# How to connect BT barcode reader correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two type of BT reader on of them is a Symbol CS3070 and the other one is a Datalogic DBT6400.

For the DBT6400 device I found an Android SDK with which the connection is very simple. But for the first one there is no supported SDK.

So I decided to connect to these device directly without SDK. Everything works fine,until the device disconnected because of sleep mode or because of I switch from one to another device.

In this case I get a lot of exception inside the while loop, because of the socket is closed. I have a tip for this why it's happen, maybe because of the coroutine, if it is possible.

**UPDATE**:  So I found the problem, a put the catch block this line of code: reader=0, and there is only 1 error, so it's seems good. But I still don't know, is it a good solution?

**My CustomReader class**

```
class CustomReader(
    private val deviceName: String,
    onBarcodeRead: (barcode: String?) -> Unit
) : BarcodeReader(onBarcodeRead), CoroutineScope {

    private val bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    private var pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = null
    private var device: BluetoothDevice? = null
    private lateinit var uuid: UUID
    private var socket: BluetoothSocket? = null
    private var connected: Boolean = false
    private val localJob: Job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.IO + localJob

    override fun init(context: Context) {
        pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices
    }

    override fun connect(address: String) {
        try {
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()
            uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")

            device = pairedDevices?.firstOrNull { x -> x.name.startsWith(deviceName) }
            if(device == null){
                Timber.d("CustomReader: $deviceName: Device not found")

                return
            }

            initSocket()

            launch {
                run()
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
        }
    }

    override fun disconnect() {
        try {
            socket?.close()
            socket = null
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Timber.d("CustomReader: $deviceName: Socket closed")
        }

        localJob.cancel()
    }

    override fun destroy() {
        try {
            socket?.close()
            socket = null
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Timber.d("CustomReader: $deviceName: Socket closed")
        }

        localJob.cancel()
    }

    override fun getAddress(): String? {
        return device?.address
    }

    override fun isConnected(): Boolean {
        return connected
    }


    private suspend fun run() {

        try {
            socket?.let { socket ->
                socket.connect()
                connected = true

                val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                var read = 0

                do {
                    try {
                        read = socket.inputStream.read(buffer)
                        val data = String(buffer, 0, read)

                        onBarcodeRead.invoke(data)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Timber.e(e)
                    }
                } while (read > 0)
                CoroutineScope()
            }
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Timber.d("CustomReader: $deviceName Disconnected")
            connected = false
        }
    }

    fun initSocket(){
        if(socket != null)
            return

        socket = device?.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery()
    }

    fun closeSocket(){
        try {
            socket?.close()
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Timber.d("CustomReader: $deviceName: Socket closed")
        }
    }
}

**BletoothHandlar class:** 
object BluetoothHandler {

    @JvmStatic
    private var currentReader: BarcodeReader? = null

    @JvmStatic
    private val barcodeLiveData = MutableLiveData<EventWrapper<String?>>()

    @JvmStatic
    fun getData(): LiveData<EventWrapper<String?>> = barcodeLiveData


    init {
        fixedRateTimer(
            name = "blueooth-reconnect",
            daemon = true,
            initialDelay = 0L,
            period = 5000
        ) {

            if (currentReader == null) {
                Timber.d("No reader device connected")
                return@fixedRateTimer
            }

            if (currentReader?.isConnected() == true) {
                Timber.d("reader connected, doing nothing")
            } else if (currentReader?.isConnected() == false) {
                Timber.d("reader not connected, reconnecting")
                currentReader?.connect(currentReader!!.getAddress()!!)
            }
        }
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun connectToDevice(device: BluetoothDeviceCustom, context: Context): BarcodeReader? {

         if (device.address == currentReader?.getAddress() && currentReader?.isConnected() == true) {
            Timber.d("device already connected")
            return currentReader
        }

        //ha változott a kiválasztott olvasó
        if (device.address != currentReader?.getAddress()) {
            currentReader?.disconnect()
        }

        val reader = createReader(device)
        if (reader == null) {
            currentReader?.disconnect()
        } else {
            reader.init(context)
            reader.connect(device.address)
        }

        currentReader = reader
        return reader
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun disconnect() {
        currentReader?.disconnect()
        currentReader?.destroy()
        currentReader = null
    }


    @JvmStatic
    fun getConnectedDevice(): BarcodeReader? {
        return currentReader
    }

    @JvmStatic
    private fun createReader(bluetoothDeviceCustom: BluetoothDeviceCustom): BarcodeReader? {
        return CustomReader(bluetoothDeviceCustom.name) {
            barcodeLiveData.postValue(EventWrapper(it))
        }

        /*return if (bluetoothDeviceCustom.name.startsWith("DBT6400")) {
            DatalogicDBT6400 {
                barcodeLiveData.postValue(EventWrapper(it))
            }
        } else if (bluetoothDeviceCustom.name.startsWith("CS3070")) {
            CustomReader(bluetoothDeviceCustom.name) {
                barcodeLiveData.postValue(EventWrapper(it))
            }
        } else {
            null
        }*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here it is my solution, I don't think it is the best, but it works.

```
const val UUID_STRING = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
class CustomReader(
    onBarcodeRead: (barcode: String?) -> Unit
) : BarcodeReader(onBarcodeRead), CoroutineScope {

    private val bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    private var pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = null
    private var device: BluetoothDevice? = null
    private var socket: BluetoothSocket? = null
    private val localJob: Job = Job()
    private var deviceName = ""
    private val uuid = UUID.fromString(UUID_STRING)

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.IO + localJob

    override fun init(context: Context) {
        pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices
    }

    private val singleExecutor: ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher =
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).asCoroutineDispatcher()

    override fun connect(address: String) {
        try {
            device = pairedDevices?.firstOrNull { x -> x.address == address }

            if(device == null){
                Timber.d("CustomReader: $deviceName: Device not found")

                return
            }

            deviceName = device?.name ?: "N/A"

            initSocket()

            launch {
                withContext(singleExecutor){
                    run()
                }
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
        }
    }

    override fun disconnect() {
        closeSocket()
        localJob.cancel()
    }

    override fun getAddress(): String? {
        return device?.address
    }

    override fun isConnected(): Boolean {
        return socket?.isConnected ?: false
    }


    private suspend fun run() {
        try {
            socket?.let { socket ->
                socket.connect()

                val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                var read = 0

                do {
                    try {
                        read = socket.inputStream.read(buffer)
                        val data = String(buffer, 0, read)
                        onBarcodeRead.invoke(data)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Timber.d("CustomReader: $deviceName Socket disconnected")
                        read = -1

                        closeSocket()
                    }
                } while (read > 0)
            }
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Timber.d("CustomReader : $deviceName Disconnected")
        }
    }

    private fun closeSocket(){
        try {
            socket?.close()
        }catch (e: IOException){
            Timber.d("CustomReader: $deviceName Socket closed")
        }

        socket = null
    }

    private fun initSocket(){
        if(socket != null)
            return

        socket = device?.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
    }
}
```